# How to reuse types from "d.ts" when rewriting a Javascript package to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion

I'm in the process of rewriting a small JS package to Typescript called [`aws-sdk-mock`](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock). This package is written in Javascript but someone was kind enough to add type definitions in `index.d.ts`.

My question is how can I reuse the types defined in `index.d.ts` and not duplicate the type definition code in `index.js` (the file I'm trying to rewrite)?

Here's an example:

The original `index.js` file has this function:

```js
const AWS = {};
AWS.mock = function(service, method, replace) {
  // implementation
}

module.exports = AWS
```

I have this type of definition in `index.d.ts` of the `mock` function.

```js
export function mock<C extends ClientName, M extends MethodName<C>>(
  service: C,
  method: M,
  replace: ReplaceFn<C, M>,
): void;
```

I currently have this in the refactored `index.ts` file. I have successfully imported the type definitions defined in `index.d.ts` and I used them to create a local type for the original `AWS` object.

```js
/// <reference path="index.d.ts"" />
import { mock } from '.';

type AWS_MOCK = {
  mock?: typeof mock
}

const AWS: AWS_MOCK = {}

// How do I define types here so I don't duplicate
// the type definition already implemented in 'index.d.ts'?
AWS.mock = function(service, method, replace) {

}
```

Since I'm already using the type definitions when creating `AWS_MOCK` types, ESLint already knows `AWS.mock` should have the appropriate function type.

Am I meant to define types again in this file, thus repeating what was made in `index.d.ts`? Like so:

```js
AWS.mock = function<C extends ClientName, M extends MethodName<C>>
                              (service: C, method: M, replace: ReplaceFn<C, M>) {
}
```

This seems counter-intuitive, especially when this `mock` function can have multiple type definitions. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thank you tremendously!